# MS Access how to check start date and first sales

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm having some difficulties trying to figure out when a sales rep makes their first sales.

I have two tables

The first table is the sales rep with their information setup like so

```
ID      |  First Name    | Last Name  |   Start Date |
```

My second table is a table of all the sales combined from every rep like so

```
Order Number | Order Date | REP ID | Sales Amount |
```

I'm trying to create a query where I can list the Rep information, and when their first sales date was.
Some help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Min http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/min.php

Comment: You can try something like `select top 1 * from [table 1] t1 join [table 2] t2 on t1.id=t2.rep_id order by t1.start_date asc `

Comment: @PrerakSola In MS Access, Top returns matches, not a single value.

Comment: @Fionnuala can you explain the Min function a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to JOIN the two tables to get the information. Since you are only interested in the First Sale for every employee, you need to make use of the Min. Something like

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [First Name], 
    [Last Name], 
    [Start Date], 
    Min([Order Date]) As [First Sale]
FROM
    firstTable INNER JOIN secondTable
    ON
    firstTable.ID = secondTable.[Rep ID]
GROUP BY
    ID, 
    [First Name], 
    [Last Name], 
    [Start Date]
```